# What kinds of checksums result in 2 digit hexadecimal?

Tags: hex, checksum, nmea

Is there any checksum that results in 2 digit hexadecimal?

I can only find NMEA Checksum...

references:

http://nmeachecksum.eqth.net/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183

I have some data file that I want to perform reverse engineering to find the kind of checksum.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Two digit hexadecimal is one byte, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two hex digits is one byte. You're looking for a checksum which produces one byte.

Obviously, you've got a simple additive checksum (sum the bytes of the input), and an xor of the input bytes.

It could also be a longer checksum of which only 8 bits have been taken.

It could also be some kind of CRC-8; Wikipedia knows about [five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Commonly_used_and_standardized_CRCs) kinds of standardised CRC-8.